# Width 100% is inconsistently computed across browsers and OS because of scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue on my website that causes the UI to break because of the width of the elements being different across browsers because of the scrollbar.

Basically I started by wanting to hide the scrollbar, and since there doesn't seem to be a supported way to do it, I used what I found as a common hack, to add 1 div to the one I want to be scrollable, making the outter one be overflow hidden, the and inner one actually having the scroll, but giving it some padding so that the scrollbar goes out of the outter div boundaries and doesn't show.

Here's a fiddle with a simple implementation:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/1/

*HTML:*

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="content">
            1 <br />
            2 <br />
            3 <br />
            4 <br />
            5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#outter {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden; /* commenting out this line will allow to better understand the hack */
}

#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;

    font-size: 128px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The issue is that while this works great on some scenarios, namely on Mac OS X using Chrome, or Safari. It doesn't work on Windows using any browser, including chrome, except for Edge when "tablet mode" is enabled.

I have some screenshots of the behavior in some relevant scenarios:

**Mac OS - Chrome:**

The green (#content) completely fills the inner/outter divs. Works great!

[image: Mac OS - Chrome]

**Windows - Chrome**

We can see that the green (#content) doesn't fill the whole #inner div.

[image: Windows - Chrome]

**Windows (non tablet mode) - Edge**

Issue also exists, although one can see that the spacing that is missing is proportional to the width of the scrollbar, because it is different from chrome.

[image: Windows (non tablet mode) - Edge]

**Windows (tablet mode) - Edge**

Works great.

[image: Windows (tablet mode) - Edge]

So, from what I understand, width 100% on the inner div takes into account the scrollbar, even though it was moved to the side. On browsers in which the scrollbar is overlaid over the content, and it doesn't take up space, obviously 100% will be the full width of the container. If the scrollbar is suppose to push the content, 100% will be the container width minus the scrollbar width.

So, is there a way to get a consistent behavior out of this? Is there a way to force a scrollbar to be an overlay instead of pushing content?

Comment: Content doesn't look very centered in Chrome compared to edge, but that aside.

Comment: That's true, but I'm assuming it has something to do with font rendering on Mac vs Windows. The container where the numbers are (green) does fill the whole parent container, so the centering thing doesn't seem to imply anything to my issue.

Comment: overflow: overlay on #inner div?
https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/2/
looks working to me on Firefox/Osx

Comment: You also can do that with absolute positioning. https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/4/

Comment: @holden overflow: overlay works on mac os, but testing on my surface in windows 10 it doesn't scroll.

Comment: @CroaToa position: absolute still has pretty much the same issue.. On mac, it takes up the whole div width, including the scrollbar, and on windows it doesn't, so the div stops 16px before.

Comment: @ manecosta I added an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This works on Mac Firefox + Safari + Chrome (untested on Win)

```
#outter {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden; /* commenting out this line will allow to better understand the hack */
}

#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding-right:8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    font-size: 128px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/7/

Comment: The issue is that it was already working on Mac OS, so just doing nothing would be a solution.. The issue is on Windows, and (interestingly) on Macs when connected to an external display.

Comment: The Fiddle you posted https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/1/ doesn't work on mac; https://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/7/ does work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm the asker.

I was able to figure out a solution that is a bit specific to my use case so I'll keep this answer here for reference, but wait on a possible better fix.

My solution uses 3 divs and javascript to resize the content (3rd div) to have the same width as the outter one.

HTML

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="stuff">
                1 <br />
                2 <br />
                3 <br />
                4 <br />
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outter {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden; /* commenting out this line will allow to better understand the hack */
}

#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
}

#stuff {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;

    font-size: 128px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').css('width', $('#outter').get(0).offsetWidth)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4pvakaq/8/